# Copy embedded structure to clipboard and retrieve it in win32

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, data-structures, clipboard

I am trying to implement clipboard operation (cut/copy/paste) on my win32 window. This window has a bunch of gdi objects drawn over it, and the window can have child controls inserted in it as well.

I have searched allot on the win32 clipboard API, and every where they have explained how to handle a single type of data, e.g. we can write text onto clipboard by specifying the appropriate clipboard format and etc.

What I need is to place ALL the data on the clipboard that will be used to reconstruct the original window after the paste operation. I do not want to use COM as suggested by msdn for embedded data structures.

Can this be carried out using the basic clipboard API? Can anybody point me in the right direction and what steps do I need to take to bring this about? I am a newbie in win32 and don't know allot about what I am doing.

Comment: Are you keeping that data in your application, or trying to send it out to another application?  If it's just in your application then there really isn't any need to involve the clipboard.

Comment: For now, the data is just in the application. But the idea is to be able to get the data out of the application as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RegisterClipboardFormat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649049.aspx) to register a custom clipboard format ID.  Then serialize your data as needed, using whatever serialization format is meaningful for your data, and store it on the clipboard using [`SetClipboardData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051.aspx).  At a later time, you can use [`GetCliipboardData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039.aspx) to retrieve your data and de-serialize it as needed.

**Update:** For example:

```
struct sMyData
{
    int Value1;
    int Value2;
    float Value3;
    float Value4;
};

UINT uMyDataFmtID = RegisterClipboardFormat(TEXT("MyData"));

...

HANDLE hMyData = GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(sMyData));
sMyData *pMyData = (sMyData*) GlobalLock(hMyData);
// fill in pMyData as needed...
GlobalUnlock(hMyData);
SetClipboardData(uMyDataFmtID, hMyData);

...

HANDLE hMyData = GetClipboardData(uMyDataFmtID);
sMyData *pMyData = (sMyData*) GlobalLock(hMyData);
// use pMyData as needed...
GlobalUnlock(hMyData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if I have 2 int values and 2 float values to be copied, I use    memcopy() on each of them sequentially and copy data to char buffer and then put it on clipboard? Similarly to read the data, I call   GetClipBoardData() and get a char buffer in return and read data in order of how i copied it?

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped me allot in getting me started. I had to use    memcpy() to place my data on a buffer, and i placed that buffer on clipboard using the     SetClipboard() method. It worked out great in the end. thank you so much!